# View data with json php mysqli in tag table

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax

I have table users :

- id
- login
- password

and i have this code to display data :

page : config.php :

```
$rep = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
$array_user[] = array();
while($data =  $rep->fetch()){
    $array_user = $data;
}
echo json_encode($array_user);
?>
```

page : list.php :

```
<div  id="tab"></div>

<script>
    $(document).on("ready",function(){

        loadData();
    });
    var loadData = function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
             url:"config.php"
        }).done(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            var users = JSON.parse(data);


            for(var i in users){
                $("#tab").append(users[i].login + "<br>");
            }

        });
    }
</script>
```

but i want to display id and login in tag table 
 for example :

```
<table id="tab">
<tr>
   <th>id</th>
   <th>login</th>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td>(display data with json : id)</td>
 <td>(display data with json : login )</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: add in Query "SELECT id,login FROM users" .

Comment: Use it as `$array_user[] = $data;`

Comment: Alex is right. Don't return the password in your JSON data!

Comment: @johansson is the problem that the data you are expecting is incorrect or not showing up where you want it in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing, you need to reference the `td` tags, otherwise you're just appending to the table itself. For example:

```
for(var i in users){
    var data = '<tr><td>' + users[i].id + '</td></tr><tr><td>' + users[i].login + '</td></tr>';
    $("#tab").append(data);
}
```

Comment: And also need to replace <div  id="tab"></div> with <table  id="tab"></table> in list.php file

Comment: also tell us how we will add table headings.

Answer (score 1):

First in the page config.php use $array_user[] in the loop:

```
$rep = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
$array_user[] = array();
while($data =  $rep->fetch()){
    $array_user[] = $data;
}
echo json_encode($array_user);
```

Then, populate the json result in the html code:

```
<table id="tab">
<tr><th>id</th><th>login</th></tr>
</table>

<script>
    $(document).on("ready",function(){
        loadData();
    });
    var loadData = function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
             url:"config.php"
        }).done(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            var users = JSON.parse(data);


            for(var i in users){
                var row = $("<tr></tr>");
                row.append($("<td></td>").text(users[i].id));
                row.append($("<td></td>").text(users[i].login));
                $("#tab").append(row);
            }



        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

list.php

```
<table id="tab"></table>
<script>
    $(document).on("ready",function(){

        loadData();
    });
    var loadData = function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
             url:"config.php"
        }).done(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            var users = JSON.parse(data);
            var table_data = '<tr><th>id</th><th>login</th></tr>';
            for(var i in users){                
                table_data += '<tr><td>'+users[i].id+'</td><td>'+users[i].login+'</td></tr>';
            }
            $("#tab").append(table_data);
        });
    }
</script>
```